# Automapper Unmapped member on List mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.2

Here are the Model and ViewModel

```
    [Table(name: "hCodeRequests")]
    public class CodeRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ArtigoCodeRequest> ArtigoCodeRequests { get; set; }
    }
```

view Model

```
public class CodeRequestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

On my razor page OnGet handler this is what i do and it works

```
    [BindProperty]
    public IList<CodeRequestViewModel> CodeRequestsViewModelList { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var codeRequestModelList = _context.CodeRequests.ToList();
    CodeRequestsViewModelList = _mapper.Map<List<CodeRequest>, List<CodeRequestViewModel>>(codeRequestModelList);
}
```

now OnPost handler i want to get the values from VM back to my model but it does not work

```
var CodeRequests = _mapper.Map<List<CodeRequestViewModel>, List<CodeRequest>>(CodeRequestsViewModelList
        .Where(c => c.Selected == true).ToList());
```

I have tried on profile ignoring the Selected property and still gives me same exception of unmapped property

```
    CreateMap<CodeRequest, CodeRequestViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Selected, source => source.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `ReverseMap()` at the end of your `CreateMap` method in order to make this mapping work bidirectionally.

```
CreateMap<CodeRequest, CodeRequestViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Selected, source => source.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```